# Loop based on null value of DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, null, cell

I'm still new to using c#. I searched many threads in the forum but couldn't find a solution. I would be grateful if you help.

The problem I can't solve;
If dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5] value=null or empty then run the code below.

If it's full, I want it to increment [i] and move to the next line.

Loop stop point = column length of DataGridView

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < **???**; i++)
{
    if (**???**)
    {

        TxtSayKod.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        TxtHome.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        TxtAway.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        button1.PerformClick();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        btnupdate.PerformClick();                    
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the data type of Cells[5]?

Comment: has an int value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify looping by using a foreach-loop

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[5].Value is null) // Remove this: ;
    {
        string away = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        TxtSayKod.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + away;
        TxtHome.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        TxtAway.Text = away;
        button1.PerformClick();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        btnupdate.PerformClick();                    
    }
}
```

Even when using a for-statement, you could assign the current row to a variable to simplify the following code:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dataGridView2.Rows[i]; 
    if (row.Cells[5].Value is null)
    {
        string away = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that test `is int` only works if the value has been assigned to the cell as `int` and not say as `number.ToString()`. Otherwise, if it was as string, test:

```
if (row.Cells[3].Value is null or string { Length: 0 })
```

This uses a type pattern followed by a property pattern. See: [Pattern Matching in C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0)

The semicolon (;) after  your `if (**???**) ;` (in the unedited question) terminates the if-statement. Remove it to have to following code block to be executed as part of the if.

Comment: unfortunately the loop didn't even work for a single row. It didn't give an error either.

Also, I don't understand how you call dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5] value=null in your post.

Comment: I used `Cells[3]` instead of `Cells[5]` in the test. If you do the correction, it might work. Also I tested for not null instead of null ( I should read the question better). See mu updated code.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work and I can't understand where we went wrong. I updated the null values ​​in the database to "0"

I updated the query as below, this query didn't work either.

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[5].Value is 0)
                {
                    string away = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                    ..

Comment: when i type the last updated query and run the program

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

gave an error.

Comment: My guess is that you are calling `Value.ToString()` on a value which is null. Change to `Value?.ToString()` ([null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)).

Comment: this worked! But btnupdate.PerformClick(); Although this button works, it skips this process on the code side. I also wrote the button query in the continuation of the condition. It looks like it's processing the code at the breakpoint, but not performing the operation.

Comment: I have no idea what these buttons are supposed to do, nor whether they have event handlers attached to them. If you have other problems, you should create a new question and don't forget to click the check mark next to the question which helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, run a loop for all rows and check the respective cell.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[5].Value is not null && row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == string.Empty)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

gave an error. :(

Comment: @SuatSeçkin it should not. what is the value of 6th column?

Comment: Value is empty/Null in database. So I want it to run the code if dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5] satisfies the condition value=null.

Comment: It gave the same error when I tried to set the null value to 0.

Comment: ten I think `dataGridView2` is also null. can you put breakpoint and check it